# Why is the operation address incremented by two?

Tags: javascript, emulation

I am looking at a [Javascript emulator](http://fir.sh/projects/jsnes/) of a NES to try and understand how it works.

On [this line](https://github.com/bfirsh/jsnes/blob/master/source/cpu.js#L178):

```
    addr = this.load(opaddr+2);
```

The opcode is incremented by two. However, the [documentation](http://nesdev.com/NESDoc.pdf) (see appendix E) I'm reading says:

> Zero page addressing uses a single operand which serves as a pointer
>   to an address in zero page ($0000-$00FF) where the data to be operated
>   on can be found. By using zero page addressing, only one byte is
>   needed for the operand, so the instruction is shorter and, therefore,
>   faster to execute than with addressing modes which take two operands.
>   An example of a zero page instruction is AND $12.

So if the operand's argument is only one byte, shouldn't it appear directly after it, and be + 1 instead of + 2? Why +2?

This is how I think it works, which may be incorrect. Suppose our memory looks like:

```
-------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | <- index
-------------------------
| a | b | c | d | e | f | <- memory
-------------------------
  ^  
   \ 
     PC
```

and our PC is `0`, pointing to `a`. For this cycle, we say that the opcode:

```
var pc= 0; //for example's sake
var opcode= memory[pc]; //a
```

So shouldn't the first operand be the next slot, i.e. `b`?

```
var first_operand = memory[pc + 1]; //b
```

Comment: @PlatinumAzure the PC is 16 bit, I think the opcode is 8 bit

Comment: I think @PlatinumAzure is on the right track.  The addition is to skip over the opcode to get to the single byte operand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis appears to be correct at first glance but since the emulator works there must be something else going on.

The relevant code is as follows :

```
    var opinf = this.opdata[this.nes.mmap.load(this.REG_PC+1)];
    var cycleCount = (opinf>>24);
    var cycleAdd = 0;

    // Find address mode:
    var addrMode = (opinf >> 8) & 0xFF;

    // Increment PC by number of op bytes:
    var opaddr = this.REG_PC;
    this.REG_PC += ((opinf >> 16) & 0xFF);

    var addr = 0;
    switch(addrMode){
        case 0:{
            // Zero Page mode. Use the address given after the opcode, 
            // but without high byte.
            addr = this.load(opaddr+2);
            break;
```

Note how on the first line shown, the memory access to get the instruction information is at address `REG_PC+1`. So the PC actually points to the byte **preceding** the opcode being executed and so the operands start at that address + 2. The opcode itself is encoded as the lower 8 bytes of `opinf` and used in the execute switch a page or so below the code segment shown.

Comment: Thanks for the validation, even if this was the only answer ;-) Just for info the situation you hightlighted is unusual. The PC usually points to the current instruction or to the next instruction. This is the first time I have seen one point behind the current instruction.

Comment: If you dont mind, I have a follow up question. Shouldnt the opcode be read directly at `this.REG_PC`, not +1? Thankyou

Comment: I have not traced all the logic but is is essentially just a matter of consistency. Having a PC value one less than the current instruction is unusual and quite confusing but if the PC value is **always** one less than than instruction being executed and you account for this in **all** the cases where the PC is referenced than all should be well.